# Items controller index method executes twice losing local or instance variable settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Update: I have posted this to github jquery-datatables-rails as it appears to be an issue with that gem or, more likely, my use of it.  I am posting the updated copy here as well with more of a description to ask for help.  Note that, while the respond_to block is executed twice, the datatable code is only executed on the second execution of the block.

I am trying to pass a variable named my_view to the Items Controller index method so that I can selectively display the results.  The current code works, sort of... In the end, the view is not maintained and any action in the resultant table, such as scrolling, causes the table to revert to showing all items instead of the desired selection.

The basic problem is that the index method is always executed twice any time a button is clicked.  The first time, the my_view variable is correctly set.  The second time, it is always nil.  The jquery-datatables-rails gem is executed on both passes and is probably involved.  It almost seems like I get two different transactions.  I've even tried instance variables and they are also nil during the second pass.  I don't understand how or why this happens.

To "fix" this problem, I set session[:my_view] during the first pass and then do not set it again on the second pass.  During the ItemsDatatable.new execution, I then must clear session[:my_view] or it would be retained for the next transaction giving incorrect results.  However, this results in the problem that I stated in that any change to the view, such as scrolling, causes a reversion to showing all items instead of the desired selection.

Curiously, I don't seem to have any other controller methods with this sort of anomaly, or at least haven't noticed it.  Can someone tell me why the index method is executed twice, and how I might resolve this issue?  Thank you!

EDIT UPDATE: I have one other controller in the admin namespace that uses respond_to with HTML/JSON options.  It also is executed twice, so it seems that may (?) be related.  Still seems odd behavior to lose all variables and execute it the second time, but I don't know.  Is it related and how might I resolve it?  Thanks...

Here are my buttons:

```
  <%= link_to 'My Items', items_path(my_view: current_associate.id), class: 'btn btn-primary kc-wide' %>
  <%= link_to 'All Items', items_path(my_view: "all"), class: 'btn btn-primary kc-wide' %>
```

And the Items Controller with the index method:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    session[:my_view] ||= params[:my_view]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: ItemsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end
end
```

Related routes, just in case?

```
                  POST     /items_index(.:format)                items#index
        items GET      /items(.:format)                      items#index
                  POST     /items(.:format)                      items#create
new_item GET      /items/new(.:format)                  items#new
edit_item GET      /items/:id/edit(.:format)             items#edit
        item GET      /items/:id(.:format)                  items#show
                PATCH    /items/:id(.:format)                  items#update
                PUT      /items/:id(.:format)                  items#update
                DELETE   /items/:id(.:format)                  items#destroy
```

The Rails datatable code is:

```
class ItemsDatatable < ApplicationController

  before_action :check_if_associate

  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :edit_item_path, :new_item_path, :location, to: :@view

  def check_params(params)
    # When using the .json suffix in URI, need to stub params so that I can see that JSON information
    params[:draw] = 1 if params[:draw].blank?
    params[:columns] = Array.new(1, {data: 0, name: '', searchable: true, orderable: true, search: {value: '', regex: false}}) if params[:columns].blank?
    params[:order] = Array.new(1, {column: 0, dir: 'asc'}) if params[:order].blank?
    params[:start] = 0 if params[:start].blank?
    params[:length] = 10 if params[:length].blank?
    params[:search] = {value: '', regex: false} if params[:search].blank?
  end

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
    check_params(params)
    @view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
        draw: params[:draw].to_i,
        recordsTotal: Item.count,
        recordsFiltered: items.total_entries,
        data: data
    }
  end

  private

  def data
    todays_date = Time.zone.now.to_date
    items.map do |item|
      status = item.status
      # If current associate has it, show where it is.
      if item.checkedout?(@view.current_associate)
        status = "#{item.status}-#{item.lastloc}"
      end
      # If it's checked out but someone else has it, show who has it.
      if item.not_available? and !item.checkedout?(@view.current_associate)
        status = "#{item.status}-#{item.location}"
      end
      # Override the above if in return status, just showing that.
      status = item.status == "Rtn" ? "Rtn" : status
      odometer = item.odometer.to_s.gsub(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/, "\\1,")
      msrp = item.msrp.to_s.gsub(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/, "\\1,")
      age_date = item.age_date.nil? ? todays_date : item.age_date.to_date
      [
          link_to(item.stock_number, edit_item_path(item)),
          ERB::Util.h(item.year),
          ERB::Util.h(item.make),
          ERB::Util.h(item.model),
          ERB::Util.h(item.color),
          ERB::Util.h(status),
          ERB::Util.h(odometer),
          ERB::Util.h(msrp),
          ERB::Util.h((todays_date - age_date).to_i)
      ]
    end
  end

  def items
    @items ||= fetch_items
  end

  def fetch_items
    items = Item.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    items = items.includes(:item_location, item_location: [:locator])
    items = items.includes(:key, key: [:key_location])
    items = items.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    unless @view.session[:my_view].blank? || @view.session[:my_view] == "all"
      associate = Associate.find(@view.session[:my_view]).name
      associate = associate.gsub(/'/, "''") # .gsub(/'/, "\\\\\'")
      items = items.where("clshadow = \'#{associate}\'")
    end
    @view.session[:my_view] = nil
    if params[:search][:value].present?
      items = items.where("stock_number ilike :search or yrshadow ilike :search or mkshadow ilike :search or mdshadow ilike :search or coshadow ilike :search or status ilike :search", search: "%#{params[:search][:value]}%")
    end
    items
  end

  def page
    params[:start].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:length].to_i > 0 ? params[:length].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[stock_number yrshadow mkshadow mdshadow coshadow status odometer msrp age_date]
    columns[params[:order][0][:column].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:order][0][:dir] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end

end
```

Related JavaScript code:

```
var itemstable = $('#itemstable').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    pagingType: 'full',
    jQueryUI: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'items_index.json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(d) {
            return JSON.stringify(d);
        }
    },
    columns: [null, null, null, null, null, null,
        {className: 'dt-right'},
        {className: 'dt-right'},
        {className: 'dt-right'}
    ]
});
```

And the view:

```
<div class="span9">
  <p>
  <table id="itemstable" class="display dt-responsive no-wrap table-striped"  width="80%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all">Stock No.</th>
      <th class="all">Year</th>
      <th class="all">Make</th>
      <th class="min-tablet">Model</th>
      <th class="min-tablet">Color</th>
      <th class="all">Status</th>
      <th class="desktop">Mileage</th>
      <th class="desktop">MSRP</th>
      <th class="desktop">Aged</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <%= link_to 'My Items',  items_path(my_view: current_associate.id),
              class: 'btn btn-primary kc-wide' %>
  <%= link_to 'All Items', items_path(my_view: "all"),
              class: 'btn btn-primary kc-wide' %>
  <%= link_to 'Recent Items', x_logs_path,
              class: 'btn btn-primary kc-wide' %>
  <%= link_to 'Home', '/', class: 'btn btn-primary kc-wide' %>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd look for something in your Javascript causing this - it can't really be a controller issue.

Comment: @FrederickCheung  I agree and am posting this on the jquery-datatables-rails forum.  Thanks.

Comment: @FrederickCheung  I posted the question on that forum and replaced the entire question here with more information and agreeing that it was likely my use of the jquery-datatables-rails gem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
def index
    session[:my_view] = params[:my_view] unless request.xhr?
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: ItemsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
end
```

Comment: That works, is clean and appears to be the correct way to handle this.  Good catch.  Please elaborate regarding the reasoning and I will accept.

Comment: There are links "My Items" and "All Items" on which you are setting the variable value "my_view". Both are html requests. And when user clicks on any of link it will call index method and sets "my_view" value in session. On the same page an ajax is also called for datatable, which calls same index method as js. But this js request is not setting the "my_view" variable value. Therefore I added a condition that "my_view" variable value is set in session variable when it is html request. So, js request will take the "my_view" variable value which is availabe in session.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the gem executes independently, without transferring control to the supplied code, during the first pass in order to set up the parameter list with all the desired variables.  It then appears to force a reload to initiate the process with the parameter list as desired.  I am assuming this from reviewing the variables during the first and second passes.  During this process, it forgets any other variables, though I don't think that it should do that.

In any case, I have to use session variables to maintain status during this reload.  I changed the controller index as follows, and then eliminated the clearing of session[:my_view] in my datatables controller.

```
  def index
    unless params[:my_view].blank?
      session[:requested_view] = params[:my_view]
    end
    session[:my_view] = session[:requested_view]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: CarsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end
```